# What is error package android x and Android J Unit 4?

Tags: android, package

[image]

I wrote a sample code and received these errors.

> error: cannot find symbol class Android J Unit 4.

and

> error: package android x test ext j unit runners does not exist

I installed the latest version of android studio and after running each code I received these errors.

What do the errors mean?

**Code:**

```
package com.example.hello;

public class JavaBasics {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hello"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add your app module build.gradle file?

Comment: hi. i added a screenshot more for module build.gradle file

Comment: new image uploded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it..
i must use

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
```

in . java and

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
```

in app (build.grade)